# How to iterate over this generic List with wildcards?

Tags: java, generics, collections, iteration, wildcard

I have a List of objects that extend another class:

```
List<? extends Fruit> arguments;
```

Now, I want to invoke a method on these objects. The invoking class has a method `wash` for each of the classes that extend `Fruit`, but NOT for the `Fruit` abstract class:

```
void wash( Apple a);
void wash( Peach p);
```

How can I apply the method wash to all the elements in `arguments`? This DOESN'T work, as my wash methods don't accept `Fruit` arguments:

```
for( Fruit f: arguments)
    this.wash( f); // the wash() method is not a member of Fruit
```

Is there any way to solve this without having to make an umbrella method `wash( Fruit)`? Because there are dozens of `wash( ? extends Fruit)` methods...

.

**EDIT**: The "invoking class" I am talking about is a visitor. And I can't alter any of the `Fruit` classes/subclasses. I can only program the visitor. This means it isn't possible to add the `wash()` method (or any other methods, for that matter) to the abstract class `Fruit`.

Comment: why don't u want wash() method in Fruit class?

Comment: @vishwanath I think it does not make sense to for a fruit to wash itself.

Comment: The method wash is not in the Fruit classes. It is in the class that is processing the Fruit. this.wash(). I've edited the original post.

Comment: Its the polymorphism, u can declare method abstract denoting that every fruit will have its own type of washing..

Comment: I can't alter the Fruit class (nor its subclasses). I can only alter the class that processes Fruit. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: @vishwanath : You can't add a "doSomething" method to your Fruit class and every inheriting classes for each processing of a Fruit you'll have in your code. For one, it is not extensible (I, as an user of your class, couldn't extend it to add my "doSomethingElse" method, and anyway, you'll just pollute your class with clutter methods. Use the Visitor pattern. Keep your classes simple, and keep the code where it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to the world of [Double Dynamic Dispatch](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Double_dispatch).

AFAIK, you can't do it easily on Java. You can do it two ways : The quick'n'dirty, and the Visitor way:

### Quick'n'dirty

You need to ask the type of the object, so you'll need a wash method on Fruit which will redirect the call to the right function according to its type:

```
public void wash(Fruit f)
{
   if(f instanceof Apple)
   {
      wash((Apple) f) ;
   }
   else if(f instanceof Peach)
   {
      wash((Peach) f) ;
   }
   else
   {
      // handle the error, usually through an exception
   }
}
```

The problem with the quick'n'dirty is that the compiler won't tell you there is a new valid Fruit (e.g. Orange) that is not currently handled by the wash method.

### Visitor

You could use the Visitor pattern to Fruit:

```
public abstract class Fruit
{
   // etc.
   public abstract void accept(FruitVisitor v) ;
}

public class Apple extends Fruit
{
   // etc.
   public void accept(FruitVisitor v)
   {
      v.visit(this) ;
   }
}

public class Peach extends Fruit
{
   // etc.
   public void accept(FruitVisitor v)
   {
      v.visit(this) ;
   }
}
```

And define the Visitor as :

```
public interface class FruitVisitor
{
   // etc.

   // Note that there are no visit method for Fruit
   // this is not an error

   public void visit(Apple a) ;
   public void visit(Peach p) ;
}
```

And then, the Visitor for your wash case:

```
public class FruitVisitorWasher : implements FruitVisitor
{
   // etc.

   // Note that there are no visit method for Fruit
   // this is not an error

   // Note, too, that you must provide a wash method in
   // FruitVisitorWasher (or use an anonymous class, as
   // in the example of the second edit to access the
   // wash method of the outer class)

   public void visit(Apple a)
   {
      wash(a) ;
   }

   public void visit(Peach p)
   {
      wash(p) ;
   }
}
```

In the end, you code could be

```
FruitVisitorWasher fvw = new FruitVisitorWasher() ;

for( Fruit f: arguments)
{
   f.accept(fvw) ;
}
```

*Et voilà...*

The Visitor pattern has the advantage the compiler will tell you if you added another Fruit (e.g. Orange) in which you coded an accept method and if you forgot to update the FruitVisitor pattern to support it.

And then, the Visitor pattern is extensible: You can have a FruitVisitorWasher, a FruitVisitorEater, a FruitVisitorWhatever, adding them without needing to modify Fruit nor Apple, Peach, etc..

One trap, though, you must manually write in each Fruit class the accept method (which is a copy/paste action) because it is this method which does all the work of "knowing" the right Fruit type.

### Edit

If you go for the Quick'n'dirty solution, the Samuel Parsonage's solution could be even better than mine:

[How to iterate over this generic List with wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420696/how-to-iterate-over-this-generic-list-with-wildcards/4420736#4420736)

which makes use of Java's reflection (I'm a C++ coder, so reflection doesn't come as a natural solution... My bad on this...). I find his solution quite elegant, even if it smells somehow (all the checks will be done in the runtime, so you'd better make sure everything's ok... Again, by C++ background: If something can be done, or an error can be detected at compile time, moving it at runtime should be avoided as much as possible)

## Edit 2

John Assymptoth commented:

> The Visitor pattern as you write it isn't an option, since I can't add the method wash to Fruit.

So I'll offer the inline code to prove wash() is not expected to be inside Fruit to work.

(I changed FruitVisitor from an abstract class into an interface, which is better)

Let's imagine the for loop is inside the bar method of the Foo class, which has its own wash method:

```
public class Foo
{
   public wash(Apple a) { /* etc. */ }
   public wash(Peach p) { /* etc. */ }
   public bar(List<? extends Fruit> arguments)
   {
      for( Fruit f: arguments)
      {
         wash(f) ; // we wand the right wash method called.
      }
   }
}
```

You want the right wash method called, so the code above won't work correctly.

Let's reuse the FruitVisitor pattern to correct this code. We will use an anonymous class inside the bar method:

```
public class Foo
{
   public void wash(Apple a) { System.out.println("Apple") ; }
   public void wash(Peach p) { System.out.println("Peach") ; }
   
   public void bar(List<? extends Fruit> arguments)
   {
      FruitVisitor fv = new FruitVisitor()
      {
         public void visit(Apple a)
         {
            wash(a) ; // will call the wash method
                      // of the outer class (Foo)
         }

         public void visit(Peach p)
         {
            wash(p) ; // will call the wash method
                      // of the outer class (Foo)
         }
      } ;

      for(Fruit f: arguments)
      {
         f.accept(fv) ;
      }
   }
}
```

Now, it works, and there are no wash method in Fruits.

Note that this code was tested against a 1.6 JVM, so I can provide the complete code if necessary.

Comment: @gigadot : Thanks. I *always* forget how to write correctly a Visitor pattern. While I understand it and its uses, I can't remember the exact code correctly, so I find re-writing an example whenever possible is both useful for the reader if he/she doesn't know about the Visitor, and for myself.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately, the Visitor pattern as you write it isn't an option, since I can't add the method wash to Fruit. The "quick'n'dirty" solution was the first I remembered, but having dozens of Fruits didn't help. Samuel Parsonage's solution, though, seems to be just what I need. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John Assymptoth : The visitor pattern doesn't need the wash method to be in fruit. I'll edit my answer to offer an "inline" version of the FruitVisitorWasher to show you.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't meant the wash method. I meant the accept method. I can't add an accept method to Fruit.

Comment: I misread your answer. I forgot my Fruit already has an accept method. I was so obsessed with this.visit( f), that I forgot I can use f.accept( this). Thanks, as I was trying no to use reflection. BUT, in case of not being possible to add accept to Fruit, Samuel's answer is really compact.

Comment: @John Assymptoth Excellent. So the Fruit's author did expect the Visitor pattern, there (as he/she should have: The visitor pattern was built for this kind of cases, which happen all the time).

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using reflection

Try this

```
Method m=this.getClass().getMethod("wash", f.getClass());
m.invoke(this, f.getClass().cast(f));
```

Comment: I believe this is the best and the most concise solution.

Comment: @gigadot : Not the best solution, because it relies too much on runtime (what happens if f is not a Fruit, or if there is no wash(Orange o) method)? Java is a strongly typed language : The compiler should be able to assist there. I have a hunch this kind of code can be quite slow (searching a method through its name...). Still it is the most concise solution, and I find it quite elegant.

Comment: Awesome answer. My abstract class already has an accept method, so I don't need to use this, otherwise, this would be an extremely compact and useful solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying

```
void wash( Apple a);
```

to

```
void wash(List<? extends Fruit> list);
```

And then use the first element in wash method.

You still need to have the wash() method in Fruit class.

wash method in Fruit class will be abstract and should be defined in subclasses.

Comment: He wants it to be polymorphic -- there are multiple `wash` methods, and he wants it to pick the right one based on type.

Comment: Note that while having the "wash" method in Fruit class overriden on its inheriting classes could be Ok for one case, it is still a big pre-requisite: One usually can't add a (virtual) method on each class for each local processing (if only because not all classes are easily modifiable to hanlde a user's special case). The visitor pattern exists to handle this gracefully.